# Solving the mean field Kuramoto model with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to numerically solve a system of differential equations that describes the dynamics of $N$ coupled oscillatory units (Kuramoto model) via their phase variables $\phi_i$:

$\frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial t} = \omega_i + \frac{K}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N \sin(\phi_j-\phi_i)$

A simple implementation with NDSolve works nicely:

```
tfinal = 20;
stdϕ = 2.5;
n = 100;
k = 1.2;

SeedRandom[0];
ϕ0s = Mod[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, stdϕ], n], 2 π];
ω = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.1], n];

trajs = NDSolve[{
  Table[{
    ϕ[i]'[t] == ω[[i]] + k/n Sum[Sin[ϕ[j][t] - ϕ[i][t]], {j, n}],
    ϕ[i][0] == ϕ0s[[i]]
  }, {i, n}]
  },
  Table[ϕ[i], {i, n}], {t, 0, tfinal}][[1]];
```

For suitable coupling strengths, the oscillators synchronize as shown in the following animation:

[image: oscillator_synchronization]

It is possible to simplify the differential equations via a mean field interaction.

Mean field:

$R e^{\text{i}\psi} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N e^{\text{i}\phi_j}$

Mean field coupling:

$\frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial t} = \omega_i + R K \sin(\psi-\phi_i)$

The corresponding mathematica code for this differential-algebraic equation is:

```
trajs = NDSolve[{
  Table[{
    ϕ[i]'[t] == ω[[i]] +  Abs[r[t]] k Sin[Arg[r[t]] - ϕ[i][t]],
    ϕ[i][0] == ϕ0s[[i]]
   }, {i, n}],
   r[t] == Sum[Exp[I ϕ[i][t]], {i, n}]/n
   },
   Join[Table[ϕ[i], {i, n}], {r}], {t, 0, tfinal}][[1]];
```

**Problem:**
Instead of a solution that is computed in less time, NDSolve throws an error:

NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.

I also tried adding initial conditions for both function values and derivatives, but that did not help.
Different "EquationSimplification" options (as listed [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html)) also did not help.

How can I solve this?

---

**Edit**

Here is the code for the animation:

```
animationFrames = Table[
   Show[
    ParametricPlot[
     Evaluate@ReIm[Sum[Exp[I ϕ[i][t] /. trajs], {i, n}]/n], {t, 
      0, tt}, PlotStyle -> Lighter@ColorData[97, 1], 
     PlotRange -> 1.1 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> None, 
     ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}],
    Graphics[{
      Gray, AbsoluteThickness[2], Circle[],
      Orange, 
      Disk[#, 0.03] & /@ 
       Table[{Cos[#], Sin[#]} &@ϕ[i][tt] /. trajs, {i, n}],
      ColorData[97, 1], 
      Disk[ReIm[
        Sum[Exp[I Evaluate[ϕ[i][tt] /. trajs]], {i, n}]/n], 0.1]
      }]
    ]
   , {tt, 0.001, tfinal, 0.01 tfinal}];


Export["kuramoto_sync.gif", animationFrames, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

Bonus: Is there a way to "precompute" the trajectory of the centroid (blue bobble) and store it in an interpolating function, so it's not required to calculate `ReIm[Sum[Exp[I ϕ[i][t] /. trajs], {i, n}]/n]` in each frame?
Of course, one option is to sample the centroid trajectory in advance like:

```
{rx, ry} = 
  Table[ListInterpolation[ri, {0, tfinal}], {ri, 
    Table[ReIm[
       N@Sum[Exp[I Evaluate[ϕ[i][t] /. trajs]], {i, n}]/n], {t, 
       0, tfinal, 0.001 tfinal}]\[Transpose]}];
```

Comment: The equation under "Mean field coupling" doesn't match the following code.  Could you correct one or the other?  Thanks! ps. love that animation; how'd you make it?

Comment: Sorry typical latex copy-paste downfall. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The DAE solver is generally weaker than the ODE solver of `NDSolve`, at least now, so the simplest way to resolve your problem is avoiding DAE system. This can be achieved by substituting definition of `r[t]` into the rest part:

```
Table[{ϕ[i]'[t] == ω[[i]] + 
     k Abs[r[t]] Sin[Arg[r[t]] - ϕ[i][t]], ϕ[i][0] == ϕ0s[[i]]}, {i, 
   n}] /. r[t] -> Sum[Exp[I ϕ[i][t]], {i, n}]/n
```

This isn't the end, because Mathematica will quit in *v9.0.1*, or spit out `ndinid` warning in *v11.2* and *v11.3* and fail when one tries to solve the new system with `NDSolve`.

So there probably exists a bug in `NDSolve`, but in which part? Can we circumvent it? Luckily a hint is given in the warning message:

[image]

The `Context` of this variable is `` discretevariableNDSolve` ``, so the bug may be something related to `DiscontinuityProcessing` in `NDSolve`. (I associate the variable name with this option because we already found several bugs related to it in this site. ) Let's try turning it off:

```
tfinal = 20;
stdϕ = 2.5;
n = 10;
k = 1.2;

SeedRandom[0];
ϕ0s = Mod[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, stdϕ], n], 2 π];
ω = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 0.1], n];

trajs2 = NDSolveValue[
   Table[{ϕ[i]'[t] == ω[[i]] + 
        k Abs[r[t]] Sin[Arg[r[t]] - ϕ[i][t]], ϕ[i][0] == ϕ0s[[i]]}, {i, 
      n}] /. r[t] -> Sum[Exp[I ϕ[i][t]], {i, n}]/n, ϕ /@ Range@n, {t, 0, 
    tfinal}, Method -> {DiscontinuityProcessing -> False}];

trajs2 // ListLinePlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OK, now we confirm another bug of `DiscontinuityProcessing` .

---

## Update

We can make `NDSolve` calculate `r[t]` for us by differentiating definition of `r[t]` to transform it into an ODE. Notice we no longer need `/. r[t] -> …` in this approach:

```
sum = Sum[Exp[I ϕ[i][t]], {i, n}]/n;

trajs3 = NDSolveValue[
 {Table[{ϕ[i]'[t] == ω[[i]] + k Abs[r[t]] Sin[Arg[r[t]] - ϕ[i][t]], 
         ϕ[i][0] == ϕ0s[[i]]}, {i, n}], 

   r'[t] == D[sum, t], 
   r[0] == sum /. ϕ[i_][t] :> ϕ0s[[i]]}, 

 {ϕ /@ Range@n, r}, {t, 0, tfinal}, Method -> DiscontinuityProcessing -> False]

If[$VersionNumber < 10, ReIm = {Re@#, Im@#} &];
ParametricPlot[ReIm@trajs3[[2]][t], {t, 0, tfinal}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The trick with the back-insertion of the algebraic equation via /. is neat. Is it still possible to make NDSolve record the value of r[t] during the calculation? Simply appending r to the list of variables does not seem to work.

Comment: @Oscillon Check my update. BTW, it's not necessary to make `DiscontinuityProcessing` a string, there actually exists a number of string options that works without `""`.

Comment: That's a fascinating workaround. Learned something new. Thanks!